# Checking the entered data for correctness swift

Tags: swift, input

How can I make a check for the correctness of the entered data?

For example, the user needs to enter a digit, and until this is done, the program will not skip it further

In my case, you need to make sure that the user entered an **integer**, and not a string, double, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by “correct”?

Comment: @Alexander probably invalid characters as OP is trying to input only integers

Comment: Don't use force unwrap if you want to check if it's a valid int. Check after wards the value if you need it. So explain better what you want and what's your issue.

Comment: I mean, the program will prompt you to enter until you enter the desired data type

For example: you need to enter an integer and you entered 44e. Because of that program will ask you to input again. As much time as your input incorrect. Also with string type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an infinite loop. If your read is successful break it. Something like:

```
while true {
    if let line = readLine(), let value = Int(line) {
        print("value", value)
        break
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: And I can save this value?

Comment: Sure you can do whatever you would  like to

Comment: Great! Thanks:)